# Spotify web-playback SDK typescirpt question

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I try to use spotify's web playback sdk, I'm stuck with specifying the type.
reference documentation [spotify Web Playback SDK guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/guide/)

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getAccessToken } from '../store/reducers/rootReducer';

function WebPlayBack() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
      const player = new window.Spotify.Player({
        name: 'Mucketlist',
        getOauthToken: (cb: any) => {
          cb(getAccessToken('')),
        },
        volume: 0.5,
      });
      player.addListener("ready", ({ device_id }) => {
        console.log("Ready with Device ID", device_id);
      });

      player.addListener("not_ready", ({ device_id }) => {
        console.log("Device ID has gone offline", device_id);
      });

      player.connect();
    }
  }, []);
  return <div></div>;
}

export default WebPlayBack;
```

The opaque type in the above function is onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady, Spotify, device_id. I searched the reference in the Spotify official documentation, but there is no information about the type. How to solve it?

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: @John Doe In the window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady part I get the following error
`Type 'Window & typeof globalThis' does not have property 'onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady'.
` and Occured same error window.Spotify.Player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enhance the types for the global `Window` object so that it knows about the properties which are added by the Spotify SDK script.  Fortunately there is an `@types` package which has already [defined everything](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/spotify-web-playback-sdk/index.d.ts), so all you need to do is install it!

```
npm install --save-dev @types/spotify-web-playback-sdk
```